# What's the internal font name of the Kp-Fonts?

Tags: fonts, kpfonts

I have checked the`kpfonts.sty`:

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{jkpss\kp@petitesmajuscules\kp@flig\kp@style}
```

It seems that this name `jkpss\kp@petitesmajuscules\kp@flig\kp@style` is not correct. So what's the real name of this font?

So how to invoke `Kpfonts` as a second font?

Comment: The low level font names are documented in the manual! `\kp@petitesmajuscules\kp@flig\kp@style` is a series of 3 LaTeX commands, which are replaced according to the package options you give. This is shown in [jfbu’s answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94762/9237).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I already commented, the low level names of all Kp-Font variants are documented in the manual. But I must admit, that this may be hard to understand.

So I thought, I should show some examples here. Regarding your question in comments see at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern} % "Latin Modern" as default font set

\newcommand*{\testfont}[2]{\textsf{#1 (\texttt{#2}):} {\fontfamily{#2}\selectfont
                           Best off (sic!) 1234567890 Questions}\par}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{Examples for low level names of Kp-Fonts}

\testfont{Roman}{jkp}
\testfont{Roman light}{jkpl}
\testfont{Roman, large smallcaps}{jkpk}
\testfont{Roman light, no f-ligatures}{jkplf}
\testfont{Roman, large smallcaps, old style numbers}{jkpkosn}
\testfont{Roman light, oldstyle}{jkplos}
\testfont{Roman, very oldstyle}{jkpvos}

\smallskip

\textsc{\fontfamily{jkp}\selectfont Usual SmallCaps vs.\\
        \fontfamily{jkpk}\selectfont Large SmallCaps}

\bigskip

\testfont{Sans Serif}{jkpss}
\testfont{Sans Serif, large smallcaps}{jkpssk}
\testfont{Sans Serif, no f-ligatures}{jkpssf}
\testfont{Sans Serif, oldstyle}{jkpssos}
\testfont{Sans Serif, very oldstyle}{jkpssvos}

\smallskip

\textsc{\fontfamily{jkpss}\selectfont Usual SmallCaps vs.\\
        \fontfamily{jkpssk}\selectfont Large SmallCaps}

\bigskip

\testfont{Teletype}{jkptt}
\testfont{Teletype, oldstyle numbers}{jkpttosn}
\testfont{Teletype, oldstyle}{jkpttos}
\testfont{Teletype, very oldstyle}{jkpttvos}

\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

For your document you should define one or two commands depending on, what you like better. I will use here the basic Kp-Font roman, as seen above it is `jkp`:

- A switch similar to `\rmfamily` or `\bfseries`: `\newcommand{\kproman}{\fontfamily{jkp}\selectfont}`, but then you have to set it in a group. Compare what I did in the example inside of `\newcommand*{\testfont}`.
- Similar to `\textrm` or `\textbf` a grouping command: `\newcommand{\textkproman}[1]{{\fontfamily{jkp}\selectfont#1}}`, note the doubled braces for the grouping.

Answer (score 7):

The fonts depend on the options you pass to the package. I have not checked the package file, but I presume you did not enclose your code within `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, as the following works:

(the font names are printed using the roman family kpfont, with the corresponding options except for the third example where I switched to the Computer Modern font to print the names)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lighttext,oldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
jkpss\kp@petitesmajuscules\kp@flig\kp@style
\makeatother

\sfdefault

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lighttext,veryoldstyle]{kpfonts}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
jkpss\kp@petitesmajuscules\kp@flig\kp@style
\makeatother

\sfdefault

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

In this third example I use another font to print the names, so as to address the point raised in a comment by `Scott H.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lighttext,veryoldstyle,largesmallcaps]{kpfonts}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}

\makeatletter
jkpss\kp@petitesmajuscules\kp@flig\kp@style
\makeatother

\sfdefault

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: As I commented to the question, the low level names are documented (it is perhaps a bit hard to understand), so your fine approach is actually not needed.

Comment: Just to head off any confusion, in the examples that use `veryoldstyle` a "long s" is being used rather than the usual `s` in the printed font name.  So for example, the internal name in the second example would be typed `jkpssvos` (I think) rather than what appears at first glance to be `jkpffvof`.

Comment: @Speravir, @ScottH.: @Speravir you were right to point out to the `OP` that these were LaTeX commands. @ScottH.: good point, I have edited my anwer.

Comment: So I was wondering, how to use `Kp-Font` as a second font for a whole document. For instance, while the main font is `Times`, how to invoke the Kp-Font?

Comment: @KOF `Kp-Fonts` has extensive math support, so it would be sad not to load the package. You can load the package, do `\let\kprmfont\rmdefault` `\let\kpsffont\sfdefault`, `\let\kpttfont\ttdefault` then load another font package and when you want to use the `Kp-Fonts` do `\usefont{T1}{\kprmfont}{m}{n}` or `\fontfamily{\kprmfont}\selectfont` for `roman` or `\fontfamily{\kpsffont}\selectfont` for `sans` etc...

Comment: @KOF If this is your actual request then you should have asked it this way! Something along “I want to use Kp-Font roman as second font, but I do not understand the command in the style file and the documentation."