# Using KP Fonts with old style numbers except in tt

Tags: kpfonts

I use the `kpfonts` package with option `oldstylenums` but I would like to get *by default* so-called classic-style numbers when using the KP teletype font.

AFAICT, the package options do not allow this. I guess there is a way to achieve this by playing with low level names... According to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94940/95418), I guess I'd like to use the `jkptt` font but I don't know where to go from there. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `\ttdefault` to the value it has without the `oldstylenums` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}

% reset \ttdefault not to use \jkp@style
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{jkptt}

\begin{document}

Roman: 1234567890

Sans: \textsf{1234567890}

Teletype: \texttt{1234567890}

\end{document}
```

[image]